# How to get the URL of referenced entity in Drupal twig template

Tags: drupal

Website using Drupal 9.

I've created a paragraph with a field that references a page. When rendering the paragraph I want to get the URL of the referenced page in the paragraph, but I don't appear to be able to do it.

I've tried;

```
{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': content.field_blog_post.0.entity.id}) }}
```

But that renders the following error;

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException: Parameter "node" for route "entity.node.canonical" must match "\d+" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL. in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 203 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this worked for me.

```
{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': content.field_blog_post['#items'].entity.id}) }}
```